# Strange issue: Magento 2.2: Wrong placeholder for password field in checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.3, magento2.2.4

I have got a strange issue in **Magento 2.2** (I have checked in M**agento 2.2.3zzz** and **Magento 2.2.4**).

When a non-logged in user enters email in the checkout page, it checks the existence of email and if the record is found, Magento shows the password field for login.

**The placeholder for the password field shows optional**, but when the user tries to login without entering a password, the validation fails and it shows "**`This is a required field.`**" validation error.

Is this default problem in Magento or I have checked out a wrong repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been reported at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16378 and someone from the community team members has started working on the issue.

As per the discussion, it will be resolved in the next updated version of Magento 2.